# Compute the radius of convergence for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k!z^{k!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Just working on some practice questions and I'm not too sure what to do with this one. I've never encountered the $n!$ in the exponent of $z$ in these types of questions before.

Computing the radius of convergence in the usual way (LimSup$\frac{||a_k||}{||a_{k+1}||}$) I get a radius of convergence of $0$. But I'm quite certain I need to account for the $n!$ in the exponent of $z$, but have no idea what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the ratio test in this case in the "straightforward" way by considering
$$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}z^{k+1}}{a_kz^k}\right|$$
as $k\to\infty$, because the sequence $a_{k+1}/a_k$ oscillates wildly - and, even worse, is undefined for many $k$.

But rather than using a "technique" to compute the radius of convergence, remember what it actually means: a series in powers of $z$ has radius of convergence $R$ if it diverges for $|z|>R$ and converges for $|z|<R$.  So, apply the ratio test to the terms which are "actually there":
$$\left|\frac{(k+1)!\,z^{(k+1)!}}{k!\,z^{k!}}\right|
  =(k+1)|z|^{(k+1)!-k!}=(k+1)|z|^{k(k!)}\ .$$
If $|z|>1$ then this tends to $\infty$ as $k\to\infty$, so the series diverges by the ratio test.  If $|z|<1$ it tends to $0$ and the series converges; so the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Thanks David. Just a few questions to aid my understanding, what do  you mean by the terms that are 'actually there'? Do you mean that for example between 2!=2 and 3!=6, we don't have 3,4,5? Also, from the ratio test, I have only ever used it for series, not power series, so we can use it the same way? Finally, how do you just draw the conclusion that |z|>1 tends to infinity as k tends to infinity, with the k! in the exponent, would this not need further justification? I can see this for without the k!, but this term still bugs me :)

Comment: By "actually there" I just meant non-zero.  Ratio test works in principle for any series but is particularly helpful for power series because $|z^{k+1}/z^k|$ simplifies.  The $k!$ in the exponent only makes it bigger so $|z|^{k(k!)}$ still tends to infinity if $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$a_n$ in your case is not $n!$. $a_n$ is the number that is next to $z^n$, meaning
$$a_n=\begin{cases}n&\text{if }\exists k: n=k!\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare the series with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^k$ which has the convergence radius $1$.

Because your series has a lot of dropped coefficients, the quotient definition is not the best idea. Use a definition that uses a single term:

$$r=\frac{1}{\lim\operatorname{sup}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} $$

Because of that $\operatorname{sup}$ in there, it doesn't matter if most of the terms are zero. The ones that survive are the same as in the comparison series $\sum k z^k$, so the radius of convergence is the same.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_n=n!z^{n!}$$
so
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=(n+1)z^{n(n!)}=\exp(ln(n+1)+n(n!)lnz)$$
From there, you can see two cases :
**z<1**, so $\ln(z)<0$, hence $$n\to \infty \implies \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to 0$$
 since $$n\to \infty \implies \frac{n!n}{ln(n+1)}\to \infty$$
**z$\geq$1**,so $\ln(z)\geq 0$, hence $$n\to \infty \implies \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to \infty$$

Therefore, $R=1$.

Comment: May I have an explanation for the downvoting ?

Comment: Hi, I didn't down vote you, in fact, I just upvoted you. I understand what you have derived, but could you explain further how I find the radius of convergence? From what I see, if I take the limit as n tends to infinity of the RHS, then the inside of the exponent goes to infinity...

Comment: @JackReacher, I'm sorry I wasn't talking to you but to the guy who downvoting me wihtout saying why. Thanks for the upvote : I've edited, I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Yep yep, got it. Thanks, very clear.